# Best ways of sending records from Netsuite to an external system?

Tags: web-services, workflow, netsuite

I'm trying to integrate Netsuite to replace parts of our payment system. Sending data to Netsuite from an our system is pretty trivial with web services but what about getting the information back. Say, I want to add Paid Bills back to our system when they are created in NetSuite as payments records on the database.

The simplest solution I thought of, was to do a search and filter by the latest inserted transaction id but the field does not accept greaterThan operator since it's a string.

Is it possible for Workflows to trigger suitescripts? i.e. when Bill is created, run this script, etc, which will then post the data to some end point?

Any thoughts or any other suggestions how to tackle this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need real time, you can have an external daemon run a search query in NetSuite every X minutes through a Web service. The daemon retrieves the records that have not been sent yet and sends them to the external system. I have used a java daemon with the Spring intergration framework and it worked well.

To monitor which records have been sent and which have not, you can add a custom field of type boolean to your Paid Bill record in NetSuite. You set it to true once the record has been sent to your external system so that the next search query doesn't return it again.

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many options here. The solution David mentioned is one option. Your current system will need an available web API (e.g. SOAP or JSON, REST, etc).

If you want near real-time payment data, you could build an appropriate User Event script on the applicable NetSuite records that pushes the data to your application's API right when the record gets created.

If you want to send data in larger batches, you can write scheduled scripts that perform a search for any records that have not been sent to the external system yet and publishes them.

You could build a saved search that runs on a schedule and emails a CSV file of the results to someone who can then import it into the external system.

As an aside, you can build the search you mentioned using the `internalidnumber` field instead, which will accept a Greater Than operator. More appropriate would probably be to use the `createddate` field ordered by the most recent.

Comment: How would the user event script push the data to an external application?

Comment: Depends on the API of the external application. If it's a RESTful API, then the User Event can use `N/https` to send HTTP requests to it.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are lot of internal and external factors on which the best approach depends. Some of these factors would be how responsive is your external system, frequency of the exports realtime/scheduled, API Limits of the external system etc. Below is a categorization of the approaches based on the frequency:

**1. Realtime Exports**

(Prerequisite Highly Responsive External System)
Deploy a User Event Script on the AfterSubmit Event for the Payment Record Type (Cash Sale/Invoice) and use nlapiRequestURL SuiteScript API within the script to send the desired data and get a response back in realtime. Note: nlapiRequestURL API has 5 second Connection Timeout Limit and 45s Response Timeout Limit. If your external server may overshoot these limits, you would want to look at other approaches.

**2. Scheduled Exports**

- Deploy a Scheduled Script on the Payment Record Type (Cash Sale/Invoice) that looks for not yet exported records and use nlapiRequestURL SuiteScript API to send out the data. Also, in this approach you can club multiple records and make a single call to external system (with multiple records in this batch) and export the data as opposed to one call per record in the previous approach.
- Second way of doing the same thing would be through NetSuite Web Services(SuiteTalk) as suggested by David above.

**3. Near Realtime Exports**
(This approach is a bit descriptive, i have listed out the high level design)

- Create a custom record for queuing messages.
- Deploy a User Event Script on the AfterSubmit Event for the Payment Record Type (Cash Sale/Invoice)
- Inside the UE, Use nlapiGetNewRecord() to fetch the record data and dump it in the custom record created above.
- Inside the UE only, call "nlapiScheduleScript" to invoke a Scheduled Script which will consume these messages. One caveat is you can only do this if you the user running the script has Admin Role permissions. So you can keep a check on role id and then execute this line.
- For Non-Admin roles, you can also create a deployment for the scheduled script that picks up these messages and consumes them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your end point using nlapiRequestURL(Suite script API) and push information like Bill id, Amount, any other data you need from the payment record. This API can be called when the Bill record is created in Netsuite. So you will get real time data back from Netsuite to your system.